# java.lang.ArrayStoreException at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

Tags: java

```
        int toSize=toMailIds.size();
        InternetAddress[] address=new InternetAddress[toSize];
        address=toMailIds.toArray(address);
```

Here toMailIds is arraylist.

Iam getting the following exception.

java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Comment: Do you want to convert toMailIds to array?

Comment: it seems like your `toMailIds` list does not contain elements of type `InternetAddress`

Comment: toMailIds is nothing but list of strings .InternetAddress will accept Strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to use a loop in this case:

```
int toSize=toMailIds.size();
InternetAddress[] address=new InternetAddress[toSize];

for (int i = 0; i < toSize; i++) {
    address[i] = new InternetAddress(toMailIds.get(i));
}
```

If a list stores Strings, the `toArray` method will not create `InternetAddress` objects from them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`address=toMailIds.toArray()`; is enough here. But type of `address` array should be `Object[]`

Example

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
Object[] atr=list.toArray();
```

Comment: toArray() returns Objects and address it of type InetAddress. this will not compile